# What is the volume of the region in the first quadrant?

Tags: calculus

We are given $$y = x + 1, \quad\quad y = 3\cos(x),$$ and the $y$-axis is rotated around the line $y = 1$.

I can't figure out what the integral is, even if I look at the graph or solve for $x$.

We also don't know what to put for $R - r$. Is it $$(1 - 3\cos(x))^2,$$ or is it $$(1+3\cos(x))^2\;\;?$$

Any help?

Comment: "...y-axis is rotated around the line $y=1$."  This seems confusing to me.  Do you mean that the region bounded by the three functions $~y = x+1, ~y = 3\cos(x),~$ and $~x = 0~$ is rotated around the line $~y = 1~$?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, the region bounded by y = x+1 and y = 3cos(x) is rotated around the line y = 1.

Comment: Do you mean the region bounded by $y = x+1, y = 3\cos(x),$ and $x = 0$?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I meant that.

Comment: Rotated 360 degrees?

Comment: you don't seem to have the right region in your work. Can you share a diagram showing your understanding of the region?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are starting with a region that lies above the line $y = x+1$, below the curve $y = 3\cos(x)$, and lies in the 1st quadrant.  It is bounded on the left by the line $x = 0$, and bounded on the right by the intersection between $y = x+1$ and $y = 3\cos(x)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: What the comment of @MathLover may (or may not) be intending, is what my next question is:  In order to identify the right boundary of the region, you need to calculate the value of $x_0$ such that $x_0 + 1 = 3\cos(x_0)$.  This is not something that a Calculus student is normally required to calculate.  If you can identify the value $x_0$ then you would have the integral of $$\int_{x = 0}^{x = x_0} ~\text{some stuff} ~dx.$$  Perhaps this is what Math Lover is wondering, as am I: how do you calculate the exact value of $x_0$?

Comment: @MathLover My initial work was the integral from 0 to 1 ((1+3cosx)-(1+(x+1)))^2. However, I didn't get the answer that matches my options. I tried calculating x by doing 3cosx = x + 1, but the x values I received didn't seem to fit into the first quadrant besides 0.88

Comment: @user2661923 I tried finding x0 by doing 3cosx = x + 1 to find the x values, but I couldn't seem to get any x values that fit into the first quadrant besides 0.88. However, when I used 0.88 I didn't get the answer that matched my options.

Comment: @kyriek you can find an approximation of the value graphically (e.g. using Desmos) (idk if that's allowed in your assignment). Though, I can confirm, it is around $0.889$.

Comment: See graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uthsdg1kij

Comment: Is it possible that you have misinterpreted the boundaries of the region?  That is, is it possible that you have misread the functions?

Comment: @joseville I got 0 and 1.231 for my integral. Is that right?

Comment: @user2661923 I'm not sure. The exact problem was: The region in the first quadrant that is enclosed by the graphs of y = x + 1, y = 3cosx, and the y-axis is rotated around the line y = 1. The volume of the figure is:

Comment: Taking the problem at face value, leave the issue of $x_0$ alone for a moment.  If I understand correctly, the region lies entirely above the line $y = x+1$, and below the curve $y = 3\cos(x)$.  Since the rotation is around the line $y = 1$, the outer radius is $R = [3\cos(x) - 1]$, while the inner radius is $r = [(x+1) - 1].$  Then, assuming that this is all correct, then whatever the value of $x_0$ is, you have $$\int_{x=0}^{x=x_0} ~\left[\pi ~\left(R^2 - r^2\right) ~\right] ~dx.$$

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you! I got 6.907 and got it right!!

Comment: @user2661923 How do you do display mode in a comment? Two dollar signs?

Comment: Centering: $$\int_a^b ~f(x) ~dx$$ can be done by `$$\int_a^b ~f(x) ~dx$$` while inline $\displaystyle \int_a^b ~f(x) ~dx$ can be done by 
 @joseville `$\displaystyle \int_a^b ~f(x) ~dx$`.  Note the use of `~` to control spacing.  The latex command of `\;` is supposed to work, but for some reason I have had trouble with `\;` in the mathSE [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) environment.

Answer (score 1):

Rotating $f(x)$ around $y = 1$ can be be thought of as rotating a shifted-down-by-$1$ version of $f(x)$ around $y = 0$, the x-axis. To get the volume, you need:

$$\int_{x=0}^{x=x_0} A_{outer}(x) - A_{inner}(x) dx$$

where $x_0$ is the $x$-intersection of $\cos(3x)$ and $x+1$, and $A_{outer}(x)$ and $A_{inner}(x)$ take into account the downward shift I mentioned previously. Namely,

$$A_{outer}(x) = \pi (\cos(3x) - 1)^2$$

and

$$A_{inner}(x) = \pi (x+1 - 1)^2 = \pi x^2$$

$x_0$ can be found graphically, for example, [by using Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uthsdg1kij). It is around $0.889$.

The rest is to perform the integration.